# Most performant way to search if row exists in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a:

```py
base = declarative_base()
class Users(base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
```

And I have supposedly a list of user_ids.

What is the most performant way to check if the user_id exists in my table?

So far I have:

```py
user_ids_list = [1, 2, 3, 999]
validated_user_ids = [id if Merchant.get(left_id) for id in user_ids_list]
```

Bonus question:

what about just one user_id? What would be the most performant way?

Comment: IT looks like you are doing a separate get for each id, of several, which will almost certainly not be as performant as a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query the database once for the entire list:

```py
with Session(engine) as sess:
    user_ids_list = [1, 2, 3, 999]
    validated_user_ids = sess.scalars(
        select(Users.user_id).where(Users.user_id.in_(user_ids_list))
    ).all()
    print(validated_user_ids)  # [1, 3]
```

> what about just one user_id?

Simply use a user_ids_list with a single element. If the validated_user_ids list comes back empty then the user_id doesn't exist.